# Is there a way to send a error msg on html via service

Tags: angularjs

This is my service.js

I am adding the childname to aaray only if they are unique, if not then I want to display an error msg on my html page

```
    app.factory('DomainNameService',['$q', function($q) {
     setChildBD: function(childBD){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
    //I am using this to check unique name gets added to childDomainName array
            if(childDomainName.indexOf(childBD)==-1)
           childDomainName.push(childBD);
             else {
    //I want to display this message as the error message on html page
              deferred.reject('Name already in use');
            }
         },
//From controller when get method is called it returns the last value stored, hence not displaying the error msg 
getChildBD: function(){
        return childDomainName;
    },
    }])
```

This is my html page on which I need to show error msg:

```
     <form  name="businessdomain" role="form" ng-controller="domainController">
          <label for="name" >
           Name</label>
            <! I want to show the error msg beside the input box -->
         <input focus="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="busdomain.name" ng-change="domainNameChanged()" required="true" >  
<!--On Ok click calling my controller method --> 
    <button  type="submit" ng-click="addSubTree(createdomain.$valid)"  id="btnData">OK</button>
```

This is my controller:

```
 .controller('domainController', ['$scope', '$state', 'DomainNameService', function($scope, $state, DomainNameService) { 
$scope.addSubTree = function(val){
            var busDomain=$scope.busdomain.name;
            DomainNameService.setChildBD(busDomain);
            $scope.childBD=DomainNameService.getChildBD();          
            $scope.currentBDStatement.push($scope.busdomain.name);      $scope.currentDomainName=$scope.getBusDomain($scope.childBD,parent,varType);
            $scope.statements.push($scope.currentDomainName);
            //Some code here
            $state.go('BusDomainTree', null, { reload: true });
        }
```

Is there a way to send an error msg using service. Thanks in advance.!

Comment: Are you including DomainNameService in your domainController? If so, we need to see this controller code

Comment: Why in the world are you using Promises ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your factory.

```
app.factory('DomainNameService',['$q', function($q) {
this.error = '';
     setChildBD: function(childBD){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
    //I am using this to check unique name gets added to childDomainName array
            if(childDomainName.indexOf(childBD)==-1)
           childDomainName.push(childBD);
             else {
    //I want to display this message as the error message on html page
              this.error = 'Name already in use';
            }
         },
}])
```

In your HTML.

```
<input focus="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="busdomain.name" ng-change="domainNameChanged()" required="true" >  
<span class="error" ng-show="DomainNameService.error">{{DomainNameService.error}}</span>
```

Please make sure you have injected this factory in your controller and then in your controller

```
.controller('domainController', ['$scope', '$state', 'DomainNameService', function($scope, $state, DomainNameService) { 
$scope.addSubTree = function(val){
$scope.DomainNameService = DomainNameService;
}
```

Comment: I have tried your code, but still m not getting error msg on html page. please suggest a solution for this. I have added my service in controller

Comment: Did you try in your controller $scope.DomainNameService = DomainNameService;

Comment: I haven't tried this. I'll try this. Thank you vineet :)

Comment: thank you vineet your code is working, the only problem which I am facing is that it redirects to next page , when I go back then there is an error msg on previous msg.

Comment: You should assign string error variable to null when you go to the next page.